As a subscription owner, whenever I try to export an Azure database as a BACPAC to a container within a datablob I get a BlobAlreadyExist error code
I have been tasked to backup and delete a couple databases; however, whenever I do so (and note that this container is brand new and completely empty) I get the following error from the activity log:
Resource
/subscriptions/XXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/XXXXX/databases/ACC_Dev

Operation name
Export an existing database.

Time stamp
Mon Apr 08 2024 15:39:52 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)

Event initiated by
XXXXX

Error code
BlobAlreadyExist

Message
The ImportExport operation failed because the storage blob already exists.

Does anyone know how to resolve this, or has advice for next steps for troubleshooting?
EDIT: Here is the JSON script included in case it helps, PII removed.
{
  "authorization": {
    "action": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/export/action",
    "scope": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<server_name>/databases/<database_name>"
  },
  "caller": "<email_removed>",
  "channels": "Operation",
  "claims": {
    "aud": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant_id>/",
    "iat": "<token_issued_at_time>",
    "nbf": "<token_not_before_time>",
    "exp": "<token_expiration_time>",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference": "1",
    "aio": "<aio_removed>",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences": "<auth_methods_references_removed>",
    "appid": "<application_id>",
    "appidacr": "2",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/identifier": "<device_identifier>",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname": "<surname_removed>",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname": "<given_name_removed>",
    "groups": "<groups_removed>",
    "idtyp": "user",
    "ipaddr": "<ip_address_removed>",
    "name": "<name_removed>",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier": "<object_id>",
    "onprem_sid": "<on_premise_sid_removed>",
    "puid": "<puid_removed>",
    "rh": "<rh_removed>",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope": "user_impersonation",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "<name_identifier_removed>",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid": "<tenant_id>",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "<email_removed>",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn": "<upn_removed>",
    "uti": "<uti_removed>",
    "ver": "1.0",
    "xms_tcdt": "<xms_tcdt_removed>"
  },
  "correlationId": "<correlation_id>",
  "description": "",
  "eventDataId": "<event_data_id>",
  "eventName": {
    "value": "EndRequest",
    "localizedValue": "End request"
  },
  "category": {
    "value": "Administrative",
    "localizedValue": "Administrative"
  },
  "eventTimestamp": "<event_timestamp>",
  "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<server_name>/databases/<database_name>/events/<event_id>/ticks/<ticks>",
  "level": "Error",
  "operationId": "<operation_id>",
  "operationName": {
    "value": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/export/action",
    "localizedValue": "Export an existing database."
  },
  "resourceGroupName": "<resource_group>",
  "resourceProviderName": {
    "value": "Microsoft.Sql",
    "localizedValue": "Microsoft SQL"
  },
  "resourceType": {
    "value": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
    "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"
  },
  "resourceId": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<server_name>/databases/<database_name>",
  "status": {
    "value": "Failed",
    "localizedValue": "Failed"
  },
  "subStatus": {
    "value": "BadRequest",
    "localizedValue": "Bad Request (HTTP Status Code: 400)"
  },
  "submissionTimestamp": "<submission_timestamp>",
  "subscriptionId": "<subscription_id>",
  "tenantId": "<tenant_id>",
  "properties": {
    "statusCode": "BadRequest",
    "serviceRequestId": null,
    "statusMessage": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"BlobAlreadyExist\",\"message\":\"The ImportExport operation failed because the storage blob already exists.\"}}",
    "eventCategory": "Administrative",
    "entity": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<server_name>/databases/<database_name>",
    "message": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/export/action",
    "hierarchy": "<tenant_id>/<subscription_id>"
  },
  "relatedEvents": []
}


Which approach you are using either Azure CLI or any language to export database to a container?

I'm using the Azure Portal website UI where you select the database, click export, you select a container and provide your admin credentials

It takes some time to store in container. So, wait for sometime and refresh your container once it exported successfully.


As a subscription owner, whenever I try to export an Azure database as a BACPAC to a container within a datablob I get a BlobAlreadyExist error code

The above error causes because when a database is already exists in the container and trying to export the same database into the same container then it throws an error. I tried in the same way and it throws the same error as shown below:

Once a success pop-up message is shown in the Azure portal then wait for sometime and then refresh the container.
Follow the below steps to export the database into the Azure container:

Go to the Azure SQL Server which is already created in the Azure portal and click on SQL Databases under settings to view the databases:


Select the database which you want to export into the container and click on export:


Fill the database and storage details with respective fields as shown below and make sure whether the database in that particular container is already exists or not:


It shows success pop-up in the portal once it exported successfully into the container:



Output:
Below are the databases which are exported successfully into the container:


That's the thing - the container is empty. I've attempted deleting the container and making brand new containers and I get the same error.

Are you changing the filename which is to be saved in the container?

I am - the filename is a composition of date and time so every attempt has a new name.
